# Custom Spring @Scope for each tenant

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, scope, spring-bean

I am implementing an application which is to support multiple tenants (users) within it. Each tenant makes use of a 3rd party service (API), although with different authentication credentials.  The approach I have in mind for this is that of initializing a custom `@Scope` for each tenant and simply injecting the appropriate authentication parameters according to the underlying scope.

My tenant implementation is currently very simplistic and bare-bones:

```
public class TenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        CONTEXT.set(tenant.getName());
    }

    public static void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        CONTEXT.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static String getTenantId() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}
```

Whilst my custom `TenantScope` class looks like this:

```
public class TenantScope implements Scope {
    private Map<String, Object> scopedObjects = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
    private Map<String, Runnable> destructionCallbacks = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    /* Standard get(), remove(), registerDestroyCallback(), etc. */

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return TenantContext.getTenantId();
    }
}
```

In my configuration, I simply declare a bean which handles communication with the external service:

```
@Scope(scopeName = "tenant")
public @Bean some_API someAPI() {
     /* Load tenant credentials.. */
     return new some_API(credentials);
}
```

However, the infrastructure described above does not seem to work. When loading the Bean declared above within different `TenantContexts`, the underlying object does not seem to change (e.g. the bean does not "sense" that the scope has changed).

```
        TenantContext.setTenantId("tenant-1");
        logger.info(some_API.toString());
        TenantContext.setTenantId("tenant-2");
        logger.info(some_API.toString());
```

returns the same object as if it were a singleton.

What would be the possible causes for this issue? Am I declaring the custom scope incorrectly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is create a custom scope to handle your scenario.
The correct and recommended way of doing this is by extending [CustomScopeConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomScopeConfigurer.html) as mentioned in docs of [Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) annotation as well.

In order to use custom scopes you must register the scope with Spring - something like below

```
@Configuration
public class ScopeConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();

        Map<String,Object> scopes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        scope.put("scope-name",new CustomScope());

        configurer.setScopes(scopes);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```